# How do i add images into an array and then display that array of images on an applet

Tags: java, arrays, image, applet

This is what I did. But it is giving me an error saying: java.awt.image is abstract; cannot be instantiated. 
After adding that image to an array how do I then display it so that it is 3x50 matrix of images.

```
public class Game extends JApplet 
{
    Image [][] bricks = new Image[3][15]; 

    public void init()
    {
        String fileLocation = "F:\brick.png";

        for(int i =0; i < bricks.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < bricks[0].length; j++)
                bricks[j] = new Image(fileLocation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getImage()

```
bricks[j] = getImage(getCodeBase(), fileLocation);
```

Comment: when i do that i get an error saying incompatible types: java.awt.image cannot be converted to java.awt.image[]